# IF inside DATE_ADD function in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySql query I need to check something like:

```
... WHERE DATE_ADD(IF(Date1>Date2, Date1, Date2), INTERVAL 3 DAY)<CURDATE()
```

But apparently this doesn't work, this condition always return true for some reason I don't know.
What am I doing wrong? Isn't it possible to use IF inside a DATE_ADD function?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Share some example data as ascii data table and expected results also as a ascii data table

Comment: @D-Shih there is no error. The query runs correctly, it just always evaluates as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use it without function `DATE_ADD`

```
WHERE (IF(Date1 > Date2, Date1, Date2) + INTERVAL 3 DAY) < CURDATE()
```

**demo with select**

http://rextester.com/KWR80225

Comment: This is the actual real answer to the question I made.
After seeing this demo working I started suspecting that my problem was somewhere else and I found it: Date1 had type DATE and Date2 had type DATETIME. I still don't know why but mixing types made the "<CURDATE()" check work strange.
I surrounded Date2 with a DATE() and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

could using a case when  eg:

```
  where (case when Date1>Date2 then DATE_ADD( Date1,  INTERVAL 3 DAY)
         else  DATE_ADD( Date2,  INTERVAL 3 DAY) END)  < <CURDATE()
```

or using if

```
WHERE IF(Date1>Date2, DATE_ADD( Date1,  INTERVAL 3 DAY) ,  DATE_ADD( Date2,  INTERVAL 3 DAY))<CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I try'd the following

```
set @b = date'2017/5/1';
```

set @a = date'2018/5/1';
select date_add(if (@a>@b, @a,@b), interval 3 day) < curdate() as u;

and the answer was 0; I try'd it again after the change

set @a = date'2018/1/1';

and the answer was 1, all as one would like.

What are the ranges of your "Date1" and "Date2"?